# Name for a stream that cannot seek backwards

Tags: naming

Is there an often-used name for a stream that cannot seek backwards? I was thinking of calling it a "forward stream", but would prefer a more often used term.

Comment: *forward-only* is an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Unidirectional` or (slightly less common) `One-directional` are the generic terms for that. Not only for streams, but also for datasets and other kinds of data readers/writers. `Bidirectional` is the counterpart.

Of course the name `unidirectional` only implies a single direction, without specifying that that direction is forward or backward, but I don't think I've ever heard of streams that can *only* read backwards, and the term is usually applied to streams that only read forwards.